HTML Rendering in Streamlit works not always
I am iterating over the sources/references of my data and want to display it row by row. Somehow only the first row is rendered correctly, others rows are shown as code-blocks in streamlit. I have not idea why.
This is my output:

The HTML is valid:
<div class='reference-container'>
            <div class="reference-row">
                <div class="reference-index">1</div>
                <div class="reference-name"><a href="https://wissensguru-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/IDTA-02024-1-0_Submodel_Wireless-Communication.pdf" target="_blank" title="IDTA-02024-1-0_Submodel_Wireless-Communication.pdf">IDTA-02024-1-0_Submodel_Wireless-Communication.pdf</a></div>
                <div class="reference-pages"><span class='reference-page'>7</span><span class='reference-page'>8</span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="reference-row">
                <div class="reference-index">2</div>
                <div class="reference-name"><a href="https://wissensguru-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/IDTA-01001-3-0_SpecificationAssetAdministrationShell_Part1_Metamodel-3.pdf" target="_blank" title="IDTA-01001-3-0_SpecificationAssetAdministrationShell_Part1_Metamodel-3.pdf">IDTA-01001-3-0_SpecificationAssetAdministrationShell_Part1_Metamodel-3.pdf</a></div>
                <div class="reference-pages"><span class='reference-page'>23</span><span class='reference-page'>110</span><span class='reference-page'>211</span></div>
            </div>
            </div>

This is my streamlit app:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Literal, Optional
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
from backend.generate_answer_lambda import get_answer
from backend.get_sources_lambda import get_sources
import time
import re

# Ensure CSS file path is correct
CSS_FILE_PATH = "static/styles/styles.css"

st.set_page_config(
    page_icon=Image.open('static/images/mhp_fav_icon.png'),
    layout="wide",
    initial_sidebar_state="expanded",
)

@dataclass
class Message:
    """Class for keeping track of a chat message."""
    origin: Literal["human", "ai"]
    message: str
    sources: Optional[List[dict]] = None


    # Read the CSS file and ensure it's loaded properly
    with open(CSS_FILE_PATH, "r") as f:
        css = f.read()
    # Append version query parameter to avoid caching issues
    version = time.time()  # Current time to ensure a new version each time
    st.markdown(f'<style>{css}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)


def initialize_session_state():
    if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chat_history = [
            Message(origin="ai", message="Hello, How can I help you today?")
        ]
    
    if "sources" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.sources = get_sources()

initialize_session_state()

def stream_response(answer):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\s+|\W+)', re.UNICODE)
    chunks = pattern.split(answer)
    for chunk in chunks:
        yield chunk
        time.sleep(0.03)

def on_user_input(user_query):
    st.session_state.chat_history.append(Message(origin="human", message=user_query))
    
    chat_placeholder.markdown(f"""
        <div class="chat-message human">
            <img class="chat-avatar" src="app/static/images/user_icon.png" alt="Human Avatar" width=34 height=34>
            <div class="chat-text">{user_query}</div>
        </div>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    
    response_placeholder = chat_placeholder.empty()
    expander_placeholder = st.empty()
    with response_placeholder:
        st.markdown(f"""
            <div class="chat-message ai">
                <img class="chat-avatar" src="app/static/images/ai_icon.png" alt="AI Avatar" width=34 height=34>
                <span class="custom-spinner"></span>
            </div>
        """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

        # Fetch the answer
        answer, sources = get_answer(user_query)

        # Once answer is fetched, hide the spinner and display the response
        st.empty()  # Remove the spinner

        # Stream the response
        streamed_response = ""
        for chunk in stream_response(answer):
            streamed_response += chunk
            response_placeholder.markdown(f"""
                <div class="chat-message ai">
                    <img class="chat-avatar" src="app/static/images/ai_icon.png" alt="AI Avatar" width=34 height=34>
                    <div class="chat-text">{streamed_response}</div>
                </div>
            """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
            
    
    if sources:
        
        with expander_placeholder.expander(label="References"):
            html_content = "<div class='reference-container'>"
            for idx, source in enumerate(sources):
                html_content += f"""
            <div class="reference-row">
                <div class="reference-index">{idx + 1}</div>
                <div class="reference-name"><a href="{source['url']}" target="_blank" title="{source['filename']}">{source['filename']}</a></div>
                <div class="reference-pages">{''.join([f"<span class='reference-page'>{page}</span>" for page in source['pages']])}</div>
            </div>
            """
                if idx == len(sources) - 1:
                    html_content += "</div>"
            print(html_content)
            st.markdown(html_content, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    else:
        st.sidebar.warning("No References found.")
   
    st.session_state.chat_history.append(Message(origin="ai", message=streamed_response, sources=sources))

st.markdown("""
<div class="header-with-divider">
    <h2>MHP Chatbot</h2>
</div>
""", unsafe_allow_html=True)

chat_placeholder = st.container()

st.sidebar.image('static/images/mhp_sidebar_logo.png', width=180)
st.sidebar.markdown("#")

with chat_placeholder:
    st.markdown("#")
    for chat in st.session_state.chat_history:
        if chat.origin == "ai":
            st.markdown(f"""
                <div class="chat-message ai">
                    <img class="chat-avatar" src="app/static/images/ai_icon.png" alt="AI Avatar" width=34 height=34>
                    <div class="chat-text">{chat.message}</div>
                </div>
            """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
            # Check if sources exist for this AI response
            if chat.sources:
                expander_placeholder = st.empty()
                with expander_placeholder.expander(label="References"):
                    html_content = "<div class='reference-container'>"
                    for idx, source in enumerate(chat.sources):
                        html_content += f"""
            <div class="reference-row">
                <div class="reference-index">{idx + 1}</div>
                <div class="reference-name"><a href="{source['url']}" target="_blank" title="{source['filename']}">{source['filename']}</a></div>
                <div class="reference-pages">{''.join([f"<span class='reference-page'>{page}</span>" for page in source['pages']])}</div>
            </div>
            """
                        if idx == len(chat.sources) - 1:
                            html_content += "</div>"
                    print(f"in loop {html_content}")
                    st.markdown(html_content, unsafe_allow_html=True)

        else:
            st.markdown(f"""
                <div class="chat-message human">
                    <img class="chat-avatar" src="app/static/images/user_icon.png" alt="Human Avatar" width=34 height=34>
                    <div class="chat-text">{chat.message}</div>
                </div>
            """, unsafe_allow_html=True)


user_query = st.chat_input("Your message")
if user_query:
    on_user_input(user_query)

uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload PDF file")

# if uploaded_file is not None:
#     upload_file(uploaded_file)

sources = st.session_state.sources
st.sidebar.markdown("")
# Check if sources exist
if sources:
    with st.sidebar.expander(label="PDF Files"):
        for source in sources:
            st.page_link(source['url'], label=source["filename"], icon='')
else:
    st.sidebar.warning("No PDF files found.")


This is my css:
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

span {
  font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif !important;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
}

.header-with-divider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #87bc49, #009bd2) 30;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header-with-divider h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#stDecoration {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #87bc49, #009bd2);
}

button {
  border-radius: 2px !important;
  color: #009 !important;
  outline: 1px solid #009;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  background-color: white !important;
}

button:hover {
  color: #009bd2 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-color: #009bd2 !important;
  transition: 0.4s outline-color, 0.4s;
}

button[kind="header"],
button[kind="headerNoPadding"] {
  outline: none;
}

.sidebar-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%; /* Adjust width as needed */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add space below the image */
}

.sidebar-image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row-reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.ai-chat-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.ai-chat-container div,
.chat-bubble {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 7px;
  max-width: 85%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.ai-message-container {
  background: rgb(240, 242, 246);
}

.sources-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50 !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  background-color: #f6fff6;
}

.source-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.source-pages-container {
  margin: 0 !important;
  border-left-width: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.source-number {
  color: #4caf50;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.source-text {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  flex: 1;
}

.human-bubble {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #87bc49, #009bd2);
  color: white;
}

.chat-icon {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.page-number {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* Styles for Streamlit App Markdown */
/* .st-emotion-cache-1c7y2kd {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div[aria-label="Chat message from AI"] {
  background: rgb(240, 242, 246);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div[aria-label="Chat message from Human"] {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #87bc49, #009bd2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

div[data-testid="stChatMessage"] {
  max-width: 80%;
} */

/* STYLES FOR V2 */
.chat-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.chat-message {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.chat-message.ai {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.chat-message.human {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.chat-avatar {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.chat-text {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chat-message.human .chat-text {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #87bc49, #009bd2);
  color: white;
}

.chat-message.ai .chat-text {
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.ai-chat-container-n {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.custom-spinner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top: 4px solid #009;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

section[data-testid="ScrollToBottomContainer"] div[data-testid="stExpander"] {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.reference-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.reference-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  gap: 15px;
}
.reference-index {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #009;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
}

.reference-name {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.reference-name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #009;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.reference-name a:hover {
  color: #009bd2;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.reference-pages {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.reference-page {
  border: 1px solid #009;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #009;
  font-size: 14px;
}


I tried everything but I don't know, why only the first row is displayed correctly.

Omg, it was just because of the emtpy line between the two reference-rows. Whaaaat

Does that mean that it's resolved now? If so, is it resolved such that you should post an answer to explain where you removed an empty line? Alternatively, do you want to delete the question and to forget that it happened?
